# How do you authenticate with Adwords using a previously cached access token?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am developing a python app where I'd like to access my AdWords account using the [installed app flow](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/wiki/API-access-using-own-credentials-(installed-application-flow)#step-2---setting-up-the-client-library), and would like to use the best practice mentioned in the [Distributed Apps](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#multiprocess_or_distributed_apps) section on that page. My AdWords API usage boils down to:

1. Initiate an Oauth2 flow, and retrieve a refresh token and access token when a user logs in to my website, and gives me permission to access their AdWords account
2. Use the retrieved refresh token and access token to access some basic AdWords information from the user, and save these tokens for later usage
3. Retrieve the access token saved in step #2, to periodically make AdWords api calls on behalf of the user
4. If the access token has expired, use the refresh token saved in step #2 to mint a new access token.

Step #1 is easy, and well documented [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#OAuth2WebServerFlow):

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='your_client_id',
                       client_secret='your_client_secret',
                       scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                       redirect_uri='http://example.com/auth_return')
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

Step #2 is also well documented [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/create_adwords_client_without_yaml.py#L43-L48):

```
  oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(
      client_id, client_secret, refresh_token)

  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(
      developer_token, oauth2_client, user_agent,
      client_customer_id=client_customer_id)
```

But I can't figure out how to authenticate using just the access token.  The `googleads.adwords.AdWordsClient` class is essential here, because that's my way of interacting with the AdWords API.  But I can't seem to figure out how to instantiate that class without a `GoogleRefreshTokenClient` object. And instantiating the `GoogleRefreshTokenClient` object requires a refresh token and not an access token.  I don't want to instantiate an `GoogleRefreshTokenClient` object every time I need to make an AdWords API call, because that will force me to generate a new access token every time, making me violate Google Terms of Service.

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is, after step #2, access the underlying credentials from the `GoogleRefreshTokenClient` and serialize them like this: `oauth2_client.oauth2_credentials.to_json()` to my persistent storage (mongo, redis, relational DB, etc).  But I'm hesitant to access the `oauth2_credentials` property without any documented support for it.  I only figured it out from the source code here http://googleads.github.io/googleads-python-lib/googleads.oauth2-pysrc.html#GoogleRefreshTokenClient.__init__

Comment: After serializing the credentials, I could instantiate the `GoogleRefreshTokenClient` every time I need to access AdWords API, but override it's `oauth2_credentials` property by the deserializing it from my persistent store.  And if the access token was invalid or expired, `GoogleRefreshTokenClient` would take care of automatically refreshing it.

Comment: I think it's fine to just use the instantiated `adwords.AdWordsClient` for as long as you need it to perform your tasks, and utilize the refresh token to generate a new one the next time you run your script. An access token has a lifetime of only one hour anyway.